# ansible before insert not creating duplicate record in the second run?

Tags: ansible

in ansible I'm trying to add a line before  '' infile. iam using insert before. it is working as expected. but when ever i ran second time its not creating the duplicate entry of " '" this is also as expected but my concern is i havent mentioned any where not to duplicate in second run why is noot adding the line again

```
- name: Change the Log Level for log in path/logback.xml
  lineinfile:
    dest: "path/logback.xml"
    line: '  <logger name="org.log" level="DEBUG"/>'
    insertbefore: '</configuration>'
    backup: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lineinfile` module doesn't add duplicates, it ensures that specified line is present in the file.

If line is not there, Ansible will add it before `insertbefore` pattern.

So, if the line is added on the first run, Ansible will do nothing on the second run – it's idempotence in action.

Comment: Thanks. Konstantin Suvorov. do you have a document where it explains lineinfile how does it check if line already exists .insert only if not there?

Comment: Hmm.. Documentation? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/lineinfile_module.html